# Facebook: OAuth deauthorization inconsistent

Tags: facebook, oauth

I'd like to preface our problem by saying we are using a server side flow to get the oauth tokens, therefore getting long lived tokens by default.

The problem: We've noticed through newer users that when they log out of facebook(from anywhere) the oauth tokens we have saved for them become deauthorized. However my facebook account, and others at our company, are not deauthorized when they log out. What could account for this difference?(Note: On my facebook account I've tried removing our application so I could 'start from scratch' so I don't have offline_access or anything like that).

Ideally our users would not be deauthorized when they log out.

Thanks for any insight,
Luke

EDIT: These tokens also expire within a couple hours. it seems like we might be getting short lived tokens even though we are obtaining them through the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was an issue with application within Facebook, we created a new application listing in Facebook and migrated to using this new client id and we have not seen the error since.

Just responding here in case anyone else encounter this issue.